# language neutral FileSystemAccessRule

Tags: windows, powershell, security, acl, regional-settings

I have been adjusting an ACL in a script like so:

```
     $Acl = get-acl -Path $File
     $rule = New-Object -TypeName system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemaccessrule -ArgumentList ('Authenticated Users','Read','Allow')
     $Acl.setaccessrule($rule)
     set-acl -Path $File -AclObject $Acl
```

That has been working well on my English systems, but I am getting a report on a Dutch system: "Kan een aantal of alle id-verwijzingen niet omzetten" At the `setaccessrule($rule)`.

The translation of that error ("Is possible a number or all id-references do not convert.") makes me think maybe the English-language `Authenticated Users` doesn't exist on that machine and I need a language-neutral way of identifying that group.

1. Are the built-in groups language specific?
2. How can I do the same thing in a language-neutral way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a computer with a different language to test with but I believe the code below should work for you.

Essentially the issue is you'd want to use an `IdentityReference` type to select `AuthenticatedUserSid` rather than a `String` representation when creating the `FileSystemAccessRule` object. [See here for the documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemaccessrule.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Security_AccessControl_FileSystemAccessRule__ctor_System_Security_Principal_IdentityReference_System_Security_AccessControl_FileSystemRights_System_Security_AccessControl_AccessControlType_)

```
$acl = Get-Acl -Path $File
$si = New-Object -TypeName 'System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier' -ArgumentList @([System.Security.Principal.WellKnownSidType]::AuthenticatedUserSid, $null)
$rule = New-Object -TypeName 'System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule' -ArgumentList @($si, 'Read', 'Allow')
$acl.setaccessrule($rule)
Set-Acl -Path $File -AclObject $acl
```

Comment: I agree that your code should work.  I figured that was the general idea, but I didn't know how.  Thanks!